# Does BSD 3-clause extend to educational material

Tags: copyright, software, licensing, open-source-software

### Problem

I am looking to teach a web development course and to help teach JavaScript I wanted to use a package licensed under [BSD 3-clause](https://choosealicense.com/licenses/bsd-3-clause/). I am unsure if using the library to teach with violates the [promotion of derived products](https://choosealicense.com/licenses/bsd-3-clause/#:%7E:text=3.%20Neither%20the%20name%20of%20the%20copyright%20holder%20nor%20the%20names%20of%20its%0A%20%20%20contributors%20may%20be%20used%20to%20endorse%20or%20promote%20products%20derived%20from%0A%20%20%20this%20software%20without%20specific%20prior%20written%20permission.) since the name of the project (not the companies or contributors) will be included when referencing documentation and introducing the topic. Are there particular guidelines for what constitutes violations of the third clause and would this use case violate it?

### What I have tried

I have reached out to the owners of the software to obtain written consent for this use case and have received no response.

(I am in Canada if that matters at all)

Comment: I don't think providing the attribution required by Clause 1 would violate the trademark-like Clause 3. I've written an [answer on this over on the Open Source SE site](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/12897/1212). For example, if you were creating a React course and React were BSD-3-clause licensed, you should not advertise it as a “Course on React by Facebook” since that would improperly suggest that your course would be official or endorsed.

Comment: In any case, I really doubt that one could say that your course is "derived from" the software you are using. Imagine for a moment that you are teaching a course about spreadsheets and you are using Microsoft Excel in that course, and teaching people to use it (using legally obtained copies, installations). Is your course 'derived from' Microsoft software, in that case? No.

Comment: Ok, fair enough that makes sense. So I will just keep it to the software name and not the company then. Thanks!